# converse of propositions tag

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-management

Recently a tag [converse-of-propositions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/converse-of-propositions) has been created

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/converse-of-propositions

There is no description and only 3 questions by the same user. I think this tag should be closed/deleted. I do not see any options of doing it, maybe because I do not have sufficient reputation.

Comment: It might be a meta-type tag, but I could see a use for a tag called "generalizations" which could be appropriate in this situation.  This could be for questions asking for generalizations of a result or if the converse of a result holds.

Comment: @MichaelBurr how would this tag help to classify and to structure the content of the site? Being a generalization or converse of "whatever" is about as unspecific as it gets.

Comment: @quid Your point is well-taken.  Looking through the list of tags, I'll point out the "examples-counterexamples" tag as something in the same vein.  "Examples-counterexamples" isn't necessarily specific to a topic, but characterizes the type of question.  "Generalizations" could also be of a similar type of tag.  For example, a question of the form: "(something) holds true for a finite dimensional vector space, what happens in an infinite dimensional vector space?  The standard proof fails, but is there another way?"  This, of course, may not be a good idea, but that's the point of meta.

Comment: @MichaelBurr on the one hand, I think ex-counter-ex is not all that good a tag either. On the other hand, for vague reasons hard to make precise in abstract, I feel that counterexample is still somewhat more specific than generalization. By way of example, there is a fairly well-known book "Counterexamples in topology" and I think such things exist for other subjects too. Even not knowing the book I'd feel the title conveys some quite concrete information what to expect. However, I'd have a hard time to imagine  what something titled "Generalizations in topology" might contain.

Comment: @quid I will take some time to think about your response.  I am familiar with "counterexamples in topology," but I think that "generalizations in topology" is not a fair example to use because topology is such a fundamental topic in mathematics.

Comment: This tag would've been appropriate for my question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1317724/topological-spaces-in-which-every-proper-closed-subset-is-compact

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I agree that this tag should be deleted it is clearly a meta tag.

To delete a tag that only appears a few times just remove it from every question. It then, being empty, will be auto-deleted within a day.

There is no dedicated way to delete a tag for users. For larger tags bring up the subject in this thread: [Tag management 2017](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/25694/tag-management-2017) (or the then current version).

Network-wide moderators can actually delete tags, and per-site moderators can at least replace at once and without bumps all occurrence of a given tag by a different one (which is sometimes sufficient to get rid of an undesirable tag).